# Finding the score function

Tags: econometrics, fisher-information

Suppose we have conditional distributional model: $$y|x\sim \mathcal{D}(g(x,\theta_1),h(x,\theta_2),\theta_3)$$
where $\mathcal{D}$ is known distribution, $(g(x,\theta_1)$ is conditional mean with known $g$
but unknown $\theta_1$. $h(x,\theta_2)$ is conditional variance with known $h$ but unknown
$\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ (if present) is unknown shape parameter of $\mathcal{D}$.
I'm trying to find the expected score and information matrix of two distributions Poisson and homoskedastic normal, so when $\mathcal{D}$ is one of these two.

I am aware of the Poisson score being $$s(x,\lambda) = \frac{\partial \ell(\lambda )}{\partial \lambda } = \left(\frac{x_i}{\lambda}-1\right)$$ and the information matrix being $$\mathcal{I}(\lambda)=-E[\frac{\partial s(x,\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}]$$
But I am not sure if the question is asking for this or not. And as far as the homoskedastic normal, I haven't seen how to derive this before. Could anyone guide me?